# How to add a same view in both tab bar and to another view. Is it possible

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

I am trying to add two views in tab bar controller. Like this..

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    UIViewController *con_view_ctrlr = [[ofi_vc_blocked_list alloc] initWithNibName:@"ofi_vc_blocked_list" bundle:nil];   // This is adding fine.
    UINavigationController *con_view_navig = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:con_view_ctrlr];

    UIViewController *ab = [[ofi_vc_address_book alloc] initWithNibName:@"ofi_vc_address_book" bundle:nil];
    UINavigationController *ab_navig = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:ab];

    ab_tab_bar = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];
    ab_tab_bar.viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:ab_navig, con_view_navig, nil];
}
```

I have not presented tab bar still. Because I don't want tab bar to show initially.

I wanted ofi_vc_address_book view****(that is added as part of tab bar)**** to show as part of another view initially. I need that tab bar in particular case only. When my case comes I want to presentModalViewController ab_navig(ofi_vc_address_book) to be shown with tab bar along with other view I have added before. But I have not able to achieve this its crashes with Inconsistency hierarchy. How can I use the same view in both tab bar and as child of other view? Is it Possible?

Comment: I dont see the code you are referring to, in this code I see two separate vcs and nav controllers being added to a tab bar.  Where is the "same view" being added to something.  Are you saying you have the same view in IB hooked up to these view controllers?  That will not work.

Comment: @stackmonster I have not added that part of code, there I'm just adding using insertSubview method. first above code will execute later I am inserting there its crashing.

Comment: Your variable names are not good. Read Apple Naming Conventions at http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/codingguidelines/codingguidelines.html

Answer (score 0):

You cant associate the same view to more than one view controller.  The way to do this is to duplicate the view in IB and hook it up to the second view controller or to create another instance of the view in code and set it on the view controller.

Comment: Im not sure I understand what you are saying.

Answer (score 0):

presentModalViewController ab_tab_bar instead of ab_navig if you want to present a tab bar view with nav view.

Comment: I am doing like you said, my problem here is I wanted the same view to shown as part of other view initially. That I don't know how to do, its not working.

Answer (score 0):

Tab bar controller MUST be a root view controller. There no way to use tab bar view controller another way. 
I see only one way for you - in view controller where you don't need tab bar, you can hide it.
But much better way is review your app architecture. I'm sure you can find another and better way to implement what you want.